# Bam file error : No mithochondrial chromosome detected from the header

Tags: bioinformatics, mitoseek

I want to detect heteroplasmy in mitochondrial genomes. I have successfully installed mitoseek and mitoseek is working for default datasets. MitoSeek 1.3 is working fine with example datasets but does not works with my my datasets.

Given below is screenshot which shows the command I have given for my dataset and its result. It shows command for my dataset and error.

[image: It shows command for my dataset and error]

If anyone knows then help me.

Comment: Well, must be that your dataset's headers are lacking the chromosome.

Comment: Thanks,                                                                                                                                I also know that but i don't know how to add mitochondrial chromosome header to my bam file.

Comment: I literally got no idea about _that_.